# Asynchronous, promises, and closure in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm new to Javascript and I'm struggling to wrap my head around asynchronous functions and promises in Javascript. I'm working with mongoose and trying to send an object of results. This is what I have so far:

```
Idiom.find({keywords: req.query.keyword})
    .exec(function(err, result) {

    if(err) return res.send(err);

    //loops through objects in result
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        Rating.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "idiomid": { "$eq": result[i]._id }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {idiomid: "$idiomid", type: "$type"},
                        rating: { $sum: "$rating"},
                        total: { $sum: 1}
                    }
                }
            ]
        ).exec(function(err, items) {
            //assign properties from items to result object
            result[i] = items;
            console.log('assigning items');
        });
        console.log('done one loop');
    }
});
```

The following is what I don't understand:

1. The console prints 'done one loop' twice before printing 'assigning items'. I believe this has to do with promises and asynchronous properties.
2. I can not access the local variable results in my Rating function. I believe this has to do with closure, but I'm not sure.

I want to be able to assign properties from items from aggregate function, then send the new result as a response. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: 1. aggregate is returning a Promise. So the order of operation is a)run aggregate b) log 'done one loop' c) log 'assigning'; 2. don't see an attempted use of `results` or its assignment - can't help.  You should investigate the use of Async/Await - it was brought into JavaScript to help with these situations (#1).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I made a small change in the code above to demonstrate what I want to do. I'll look up async and await and see how I can use that.

Comment: results !== result :-) - So result is available in your matcher but not in callback?

Comment: Ahh.. gotcha. The variable result is available, but not result[i]. My guess is that the callback executes after the loop, so the variable i is out of range. Seems like my second issue is related to the first issue. I'm looking at asyncs and awaits and there doesn't seem to be a clean solution for aggregates. Am I going about this the right way? Should I avoid nesting in this case?

Comment: yes - the answer below has a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the entire function by splitting it into several async functions. This will wait for the queries to complete before executing the next line.

```
idiomController.search = async(req, res, next) => {
    var results = await findIdiom(req.query.keyword);
    var temp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var agg = await aggregateResults(results[i]);
        temp.push({
            rating: agg[0].rating,
            total: agg[0].total
        });
    }
    //handle response
}

aggregateResults = (result) => {
    return Rating.aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$match": {
                    "idiomid": { "$eq": result._id }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {idiomid: "$idiomid", type: "$type"},
                    rating: { $sum: "$rating"},
                    total: { $sum: 1}
                }
            }
        ]
    );
}

findIdiom = (keyword) => {
    return Idiom.find({keywords: keyword});
}
```